# Building CEPH on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina): CMake Problem: More than one input file specified

Tags: assembly, cmake, nasm, macos-catalina, ceph

I'm trying to build CEPH Pacific (16.x) on MacOS to be able to mount a CEPH Cluster. Having worked out a lot of problems and gaps in the official documentation, I'm currently hanging on an error, which I cannot solve:

During the compilation, the following error is being thrown:

```
[  9%] Building ASM object src/common/CMakeFiles/crc32.dir/__/isa-l/crc/crc32_iscsi_00.asm.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk: fatal: more than one input file specified: /Users/codebaard/dev/ceph/src/isa-l/crc/crc32_iscsi_00.asm

make[2]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/crc32.dir/__/isa-l/crc/crc32_iscsi_00.asm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/common/CMakeFiles/crc32.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My research resulted in being a problem with CMake Versions >3.19.x, which presumably is setting some flags with NASM wrong, resulting in this anomaly during the build. The easy solution would be using CMake 3.18.4, which supposedly doesn't have this error. This didn't help in my case though.
Actually, the line, which presumably causes the error is at (ceph-repository):/src/common/CMakeLists.txt:211:

```
  if(HAVE_NASM_X64)
    set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "-i ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/isa-l/include/ ${CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS}")
    list(APPEND crc32_srcs
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/isa-l/crc/crc32_iscsi_00.asm
      crc32c_intel_fast_zero_asm.s)
  endif(HAVE_NASM_X64)
```

If I comment out this section, the error disappears, which confirms my theory but subsequently the linker fails, due to missing binaries - likely from this step.

So the question is: does someone have an idea, what at least is going on here? And if so, how could a fix look like?

This would be such a milestone even, since there aren't any real sources on the internet on how to make ceph work on MacOS and I would love to see more widespread use.

Comment: Just an observation: You mention MacOS 10.15 (Catalina), yet in the cmake output you've got `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk`...

Comment: Actually very nice, to point this out! I haven't seen this! Probably not the solution to that particular problem but might have solved other problems before they appeared! Thanks :-)